# Class not found after maven package, but can see it in IDEA denpendies

Tags: java, maven, jar, classnotfoundexception

My java application cast `class not exception` on class `org.apache.htrace.shaded.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl`, from IDEA I can see the class can be found in my dependency:

[image]

but when I get into the jar, only some class left in the package `org.apache.htrace.shaded.commons.logging`, and without `impl` package in it:

```
jar -tf GIS-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar | fgrep org/apache/htrace/shaded/commons
org/apache/htrace/shaded/commons/
org/apache/htrace/shaded/commons/logging/
org/apache/htrace/shaded/commons/logging/Log.class
org/apache/htrace/shaded/commons/logging/LogConfigurationException.class
org/apache/htrace/shaded/commons/logging/LogFactory$1.class
org/apache/htrace/shaded/commons/logging/LogFactory$2.class
org/apache/htrace/shaded/commons/logging/LogFactory$3.class
org/apache/htrace/shaded/commons/logging/LogFactory$4.class
org/apache/htrace/shaded/commons/logging/LogFactory$5.class
org/apache/htrace/shaded/commons/logging/LogFactory$6.class
org/apache/htrace/shaded/commons/logging/LogFactory.class
```

Also, some and other class exists, which was not in the above picture. And the class I want `LogFactoryImpl` is not there, so the `class not found` exception occur.

I have analysis the Maven dependency, and make sure no conflict. What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this.

It's something due to the version of maven-shade-plugin.

In my pom.xml I didn't set a `version`, so some strange happens. After I set the `version`, the problem solved.